# Tomatousb, ls command is broken and returns just the query

Tags: bash, ls, dropbear

I made ipkg upgrade on my old tomatousb, which it seems resulted at least in a broken ls command:

```
  [root@tomatousb root]$ /bin/ls /
   /
  [root@tomatousb root]$ ls /bin
   /bin
```

however, the results are displayed in different colours. 
There is also strange behaviour:

```
   [root@tomatousb root]$ echo $PATH
   echo $PATH
   sh: echo: Permission denied

   [root@tomatousb root]$ /bin/echo $PATH
   /bin/echo $PATH
   /opt/bin:/opt/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

I have no glue what's wrong to it. 
The logs I see are as following:

```
 /var/log/messages
 Jan  1 04:00:11 tomatousb user.info kernel: ipt_recent v0.3.1: Stephen Frost <sfrost@snowman.net>.  http://snowman.net/projects/ipt_recent/
 Jan 31 23:10:21 tomatousb user.notice root: <<<< MPCSD: Config-files not found in /jffs/config/mpcs & /opt/etc/mpcs!!! Exit. >>>>
 Jan 31 23:11:02 tomatousb cron.err crond[143]: time disparity of 25290430 minutes detected
 Jan 31 23:37:26 tomatousb authpriv.info dropbear[505]: Child connection from *.*.*.*:*
```

So, basically, when I do SSH, I get to dropbear. 
It seems that during the last ipkg upgrade I got new bash, tcpdump, and two more items, but I can't recall which exactly.. And I can't find the ipkg logfile...

Comment: looks not programming related, you should try your question in a more specific forum like superuser.com or serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I bumped into my own old discussion when I had the same issue with the same box, and here's what was the reason:

```
    [root@tomatousb mnt]$ cat /opt/etc/profile
    #
    # Bash initialization script
    #

    PS1="[\u@\h \W]$ "
    PATH=/opt/sbin:/opt/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

    export PS1 PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    [root@tomatousb mnt]$ rm /opt/etc/profile
```

Then I did reboot, and everything restored back to normal operation!
Do not know what exactly was in that profile file that ruined everything and caused 'memory exhausted' error when running vi.